# Extend python's dict functionality to user created classes

Tags: python, dictionary, extend

Is it possible to add dict functionality to user created classes?

ie:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
       self.x
       self.y
    def __dict__(self):
       return {'x': self.x, 'y': self.y}

f = Foo()
dict(f) <-- throws TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
```

Comment: Do you just want to be able to pass it to dict() or would you rather it act like a dictionary so you could do `f = Foo(); print f['x']`? Both are possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dict` constructor expects either a mapping or an iterable of key/value pairs as a parameter, so your class needs to either implement the mapping protocol or be iterable.

Here's an example how to got about the latter approach:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
    def __iter__(self):
       return vars(self).iteritems()
```

Example usage:

```
>>> dict(Foo(2, 3))
{'x': 2, 'y': 3}
```

I don't know how useful this is, though.  You could just do

```
>>> vars(Foo(2, 3))
{'x': 2, 'y': 3}
```

which would work without implementing `__iter__()` on your class.

Comment: or I could just call vars(my_object) :)